# Add block using Custom Layout Updates to category

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am trying use the Custom Layout Update field of a category to add something to the left sidebar for just this category but can't quite get it to work. I had it working before so I know I can do it but then my client accidentally deleted the category.

This works, so I know I have the ability to add something - but I don't want a static block:

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="cms/block" name="Designer Sidebar" before="-">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>designer_sidebar</block_id></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

I want to include a phtml file from my theme folder and trying this, but can't get it to output anything:

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="cms/block" name="Designer Sidebar" before="-" template="catalog/category/view_sidebar.phtml" />
</reference>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<reference name="left">
      <block type="core/template" name="Designer Sidebar"  template="catalog/category/view_sidebar.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Comment: Or suited, helped you?